# tty1 black screen after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 15.10, 16.04, tty

I updated 15.10 to 16.04 and now it shows black screen with tty1 instead of desktop.

When I run `startx` it shows desktop but without menu, taskbar, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be a solution but I have no way of checking if it doesn't work you can always rename the file back .. try

```
mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.old
```

and then try rebooting again

Comment: did not work.:(

Comment: ok .. wasnt sure but thought i would let you give it a try .. you can just rename the old one back to make sure if you fix your issue nothing changes